# REST webservice object mismatching Hibernate relationship (passing id instead the object)

Tags: hibernate, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following model classes:

```
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "iduser")
    private Integer idUser;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "passwd")
    private String passwd;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idusersgroup", referencedColumnName = "idusersgroup")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private UsersGroups idUsersGroup;
    .
    .
    .
}

public class UsersGroups implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idusersgroup")
    private Integer idUsersGroup;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So I wrote a service to access to the `Users` data:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createUser(Users user) {
    Users login;
    UsersDAO u = new UsersDAO();

    if(user.getLogin() == null || user.getDescription() == null || 
            user.getNif() == null || user.getPasswd() == null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Missing information").build();
    try{
        u.addUser(user);
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("User already exists").build();
    }
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
}
```

The problem is I don't want to pass the parameter of the relationship as an object in the JSON, but just passing its id instead. Something like this:

```
{
    "login": "admin2",
    "passwd": "12345",
    "idusersgroup": 1
}
```

But with this implementation, `idUsersGroup` is expected to be an instance of `UsersGroup`, not its id.
What would be the best way to achieve this? Changing how the relationship is implemented in model classes? Changing the format of JSON object to present `idUsersGroup` as a nested object? Any other option? I'm new to hibernate and still understanding how relationships should be defined in every case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JPA/Hibernate, we are expected to handle relationships ourselves. So basically what you need to do is look up the `UserGroup` (however you look it up), then set the `UserGroup` on the `User`. This will allow the `UserGroup` id to be persisted with the `User`

```
UserGroupDao ugDao = new UserGroupDao();
UserGroup uGroup = ugDao.findOne(user.getIdusersgroup());
user.setIdUsersGroup(uGroup);
u.addUser(user);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess with this I should be able to solve the Hibernate side of the call. The problem is in the JSON though. If the service consumes a JSON and I define as a `Users` bean, this bean is expecting to receive an `UsersGroup` object, but it's receiving an `int` instead, so the `user.getIdUsersGroup()` always returns `null`. Should I discard the idea of using a bean and directly parsing as a JSON object to obtain this id? Or there is any workaround to achieve this without writing more code? I thought about passing this id in the url, but it doesn't seem a very elegant solution to me

Comment: Generally with relationships, there is also some indication of a relation in the URL. for example `usersgroup/1/users`. With this URL, the `1` can be extracted from the URL. There are some semantics to URLs. For example, the previous URL says _"the users that belong the the users group with id 1"_. So if you post to that URL, you are saying you want to create a user for that user group.

Comment: On the other hand, if a user already exists, you wouldn't want to create a new user. All you want to do is connect the user and and use group. There are different ways of handling this. Some might just send the URL (or an id) of the user to the user group URL, and from that information you can make the connection.

Comment: Other than that (if you want to stick to what you're doing), as far as the user id, just change the property name in the JSON so it doesn't interfere with user group property

Comment: Thanks again, if I change the property name in the JSON, I suppose I should add a `@Transient` annotated field in the model class with the same name and type. It's that ok? I'm trying this implementation but I can't make it work

Comment: Yeah, I imagine that should work. What's not working about it?

Comment: When I get this field inside the service, it returns 0 (and the value in the JSON isn't that, so I assume the field's value is not being added to the object). Summarizing, I added a `private int idGroup` with `@Transient` annotation to the `Users` class, added the get and set methods too and included in the constructor. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Might be a problem with the serializer (probably Jackson). Something I would need to test out. Maybe Jackson also recognizes the `@Transient` and doesn't serialize it. (If it is Jackson you're using), You can try to add `@JsonProperty("idGroup")` on the setter.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jackson, unfortunately adding that annotation to the setter didn't make the trick :( Anyway, thanks a lot for your effort, as this problem it's different from original, I'm opening a new question, maybe someone has stepped into this particular issue

Comment: For the record: my bad, I'm using Genson, not Jackson